# Helmrelease cannot find Helmsource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, fluxcd

When I try to apply Helmrelease Flux cannot find the source but the source actually exists.

I use Artifact Registry (GCP) for Helm chart repo.
Here is the Flux command I used to create it:

```
flux create source oci regapp-repo \
--url=oci://us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/XXXXXX/regapp-helm-charts/regapp-chart \
--tag=0.1.0 \
--interval=10m \
--namespace=development \
--secret-ref=artifact-registry
```

The commnd is working, here is the corresponding logs (flux get sources all -A):

```
NAMESPACE   NAME                            REVISION                SUSPENDED   READY   MESSAGE
development ocirepository/regapp-repo       0.1.0@sha256:fbb4b784   False       True    stored artifact for digest '0.1.0@sha256:fbb4b784'
```

But the problem is when I'm trying to create a Helm release using the command:

```
flux create hr regapp-release \
--interval=10m \
--source=HelmRepository/regapp-repo.development \
--chart=regapp-chart \
--chart-version="0.1.0" \
--namespace=development
```

finally I'm getting the following error:
`✗ client rate limiter Wait returned an error: context deadline exceeded`

and if we chek logs (using kubectl get events -n development --field-selector type=Warning) we will see:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                 MESSAGE
13h         Warning   SourceUnavailable   helmchart/development-regapp-release   failed to get source: HelmRepository.source.toolkit.fluxcd.io "regapp-repo" not found
```

Comment: Should the name of repository be "ocirepository/regapp-repo" ? 
Accourind to the error message would try to check this firs

Comment: Thank you for your try to help, however, I've already switched to Argo CD, but I tried your solution, here is the log: 
invalid argument "HelmRepository/ocirepository/regapp-repo.development" for "--source" flag: invalid helm chart source 'HelmRepository/ocirepository/regapp-repo.development', must be in format <kind>/<name>

Answer (score 0):

Your source is not a helmRepository, you created an ociRepository, so your command should look like this:

```
  flux create hr regapp-release \
--interval=10m \
--source=OCIRepository/regapp-repo.development \
--chart=regapp-chart \
--chart-version="0.1.0" \
--namespace=development
```